# DataMapper Error in Sinatra - NameError: Cannot find the child_model

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

Using Sinatra and DataMapper. This is my first time trying to use more than two model classes. Not sure what is causing the error.  Thanks.

The error:

```
NameError: Cannot find the child_model ContactNote for Contact in contact_notes
```

The models:

```
class Contact
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :fullname, Text, :required => true
    property :email, Text
    property :phone, Text
    has n, :contact_notes
    has n, :projects
end

class Contact_Note
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :contact_content, Text, :required => true
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime
    belongs_to :contact
end

class Project
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :project_name, Text, :required => true
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime
    belongs_to :contact
    has n, :project_notes
end


class Project_Note
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :project_content, Text, :required => true
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime
    belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datamapper makes expectations on class names based on ruby conventions. It expects your contact notes to be in a `ContactNote` class, while you've named it `Contact_Note`, hence the error it can't find ContactNote.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I noticed that even if I change the class to ContactNote I have to leave the association property as :contact_notes. If I remove the underscore there I get a similar error. Is this another datamapper convention?

Comment: This is a ruby convention in general.